# In pyqt how do I use for loops to insert data at tablewidgets?

Tags: python, pyqt

I have some tablewidgets,in which I want to insert some data.To do this,i use the following:

```
for index,i in enumerate(list1):
   item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
   item.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", str(i), None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
   item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter|QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
   self.tableWidget_1.setItem(0, index, item)
```

At this moment I do this for every tablewidget.I thought maybe I could write a simple function, something like this:

```
def function_1(list1,number_of_tablewidget):
    for index,i in enumerate(list1):
       item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
       item.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", str(i), None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
       item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter|QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
       self.tableWidget_number_of_tablewidget.setItem(0, index, item)
```

My concern is about number_of_tablewidget. The variable will be a number, so how will I fit it with the last line? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just send the `QTableWidget` object to your function and use as such:

```
def function_1(item_list,tablewidget):
    for index, i in enumerate(item_list):
       #...
       tablewidget.setItem(0, index, item)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use getattr() to evaluate attribute names dynamically:

```
def function_1(list1,number_of_tablewidget):
    for index,i in enumerate(list1):
       item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
       item.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", str(i), None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
       item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter|QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
       getattr(self, "tableWidget_%d" % number_of_tablewidget).setItem(0, index, item)
```